# Ubuntu 17.10 laptop doesn't suspend on lid close

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop

Thinkpad T450 running Ubuntu 17.10 which was clean-installed (not upgraded) some weeks back. I frequently moved from room to room and like the laptop to go to sleep when I close the lid. It seems to never do this, staying awake all the time. I have to hold down the power button in the indicator and choose the pause icon to suspend it. Previous releases of Ubuntu used to "Just Work".

I have tried toggling the option in Tweaks to ensure it is set to suspend on lid close, but this makes no difference. Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, the suspend action works properly from the power button (you can also press the 'alt' key to get the pause icon) but not when activated by the laptop lid.  Can you run `tweak` (perhaps `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`), check in the 'power' section and check that the ability to suspend on lid is turned on?

Comment: Probably a bug, but also probably can be worked around, would that be an acceptable answer to you?

Comment: As already mentioned in the question, I have already checked in the tweaks tool.

Comment: I'd like to understand why this doesn't work, and what can be done to make it work.

Comment: Does this work: https://askubuntu.com/a/395440/689314

Comment: What does `systemd-inhibit --list` say?

Comment: @RobieBasak http://paste.ubuntu.com/26175450/ - output from `systemd-inhibit --list`

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, it was in reply to Charles, the comment above yours.

Comment: @popey thanks. That matches mine (I'm also on 17.10) and my suspend on lid close works, so that eliminates that potential cause I think. My suspend on lid close did stop working during the 17.10 dev cycle, but it was restored with the tweak tool so it sounds like you have some other root cause :-/

Comment: What's the output of: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action & 
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action` ?

Comment: @Fabby 'suspend' 'suspend'

Comment: @popey: no further action from me then...

Comment: Is `acpid` running? If so, can you try booting a kernel from a previous release that definitely worked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out we were all wrong. The magnet which triggers the lid sensor had come away inside the laptop. I confirmed this by holding a fridge magnet up to the camera. As soon as I did that, the laptop suspended fine. So I figured there's a magnet in the base. There was, but it was floating around (clinging to the battery) inside the machine. I put it back in place and it's now working.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

We can catch the lid open/close events and could bind scripts to them by using [`acpid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/acpid.8.html) - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon.

- In attempt to check whether this suggestion works I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my DELL Vostro 3350. Then I've used `dconf-editor` to disable the lid close action. But unfortunately I can't disable this action... So I just hope this could help you.

**1.** Catch the events. Execute one of the next commands, then close and open the lid: `acpi_listen` or `netcat -U /var/run/acpid.socket`. Here is an example output:

```bsh
$ acpi_listen
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open
```

**2.** Configure `acpid` to recognize the events triggered when the device mode is changed. Create the following files (don't forgot to use the actual events from the above step):

- `/etc/acpi/events/lid-close`:

  ```bsh
  # /etc/acpi/events/lid-close 
  # This is called when the lid is closed
  event=button/lid LID close
  action=/etc/acpi/lid-actions.sh 1
  ```
- `/etc/acpi/events/lid-open`:

  ```bsh
  # /etc/acpi/events/lid-open
  # This is called when the lid is open
  event=button/lid LID open
  action=/etc/acpi/lid-actions.sh 0
  ```

**3.** Restart `acpid` so it can re-read the event filters, including the ones we just added:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart acpid.service
```

**4.** Create the script `/etc/acpi/lid-actions.sh` (and make it executable) that will suspend the laptop when the lid is close `1`. I don't have idea what action could be useful when the lid is going to be open `0`, so these lines are commented.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" -eq 1 ]; then systemctl suspend  # Lid is close
#elif [ "${1}" -eq 0 ]; then                 # Lid is open
fi
```

References:

- [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980997/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-when-the-lid-is-twisted-or-closed) This is the main source.
- ThinkWiki: [Installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Thinkpad Twist](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thinkpad-acpi) | [Thinkpad-acpi](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Wacom_Serial_Tablet_PC_Stylus) | [Wacom Tablet Stilus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1635686)
- [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)
- [How do I re-activate (wake?) the monitors from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12307/how-do-i-re-activate-wake-the-monitors-from-the-command-line) - not implemented here.

Comment: acpi_listen returns _nothing_ when I close the lid or open it.

Comment: Hi. @popey, sorry to hear that. IMO, It looks like some kernel module is not enabled. Does `acpi_listen` work with the **Fn** keys or the power button?

Comment: Yes, acpi_listen reports when volume up/down or other function keys are pressed.

Comment: @popey, please read the bottom of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975574/566421). If I remember right, I also had uncaught events before install these packages - maybe the last one is enough.

Answer (score 0):

### The fastest way is by using the default settings manager

1. Go to `Settings>Power Management>When laptop lid closed`
2. Select "Suspend" instead of "Do nothing" and hit apply
3. All done

---

*P.s : why use ubuntu tweaks when there is a option to do it in default settings app*

Comment: I'm not seeing what you describe in Ubuntu 17.10 running the Gnome desktop. Does this exist on the native(modified Gnome) Ubuntu DE? I see Settings>Power, but from there no reference to anything laptop lid related.

Comment: I'm sure the option was there(i'm using kbuntu rn so its hard to back up ubuntu claims ) sorry