# Ubuntu 17.10.1 doesn't suspend on lid close with 2 displays

Tags: suspend, laptop, acer, acpi, lid

I run Ubuntu 17.10.1 on Acer Aspire V17 Nitro (VN7-791G).
I am booting from a secondary hard drive that is installed instead of a DVD drive, I also have a secondary display connected using a VGA (monitor) to HDMI (laptop) converter.

Originally when I closed the lid, the laptop panel would turn off and the second monitor would become a primary monitor instead of suspending.

These are the relevant settings from `gsettings`, which seem correct:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

I have edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` adding this line without any effect too:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

My `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf" seems fine as well, it contains:

```
# Do we ignore the lid state
#  [...]
# default=false
IgnoreLid=false
```

When I tried `acpi_listen` and closed and opened the lid, I got this:

```
jack/lineout LINEOUT unplug
jack/videoout VIDEOOUT unplug
jack/lineout LINEOUT plug
jack/videoout VIDEOOUT plug
button/lid LID open
jack/lineout LINEOUT unplug
jack/videoout VIDEOOUT unplug
jack/lineout LINEOUT plug
jack/videoout VIDEOOUT plug
```

Then I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/985711/367990)
and got my suspending to work, but after opening the lid the screen flashes and then asks me to login. When I then login, the screen flashes and then makes me swipe and login again (all opened programs are lost and sometimes doesen't even let me open them again).

One more note: I am using a swap-file instead of a swap-partition.

How can I make Ubuntu laptop suspend on lid close even if an external monitor is connected?

Comment: I had the same problem, suspend working fine with one screen but lid close had no effect with two. Have a look here: [Power suspend on Ubuntu with an external monitor](https://apiraino.github.io/2018/08/06/ubuntu_gnome_power.html)
, a very detailed story about several things that can be configured. This helped in my case.